# Code Mirror find functions first

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am using code mirror to build some coding exercises for a class I teach. I have it setup so that code mirror retrieves code one line at a time, highlighting the current line so students can see each step as it is executed.

The issue is I want students to have the ability to create their own functions, but I can't do that reading the code line by line. I need to first find any user defined functions. Then if the user calls that function I need to jump to that function, read the lines inside the function, and then return back to where the user called the function to continue reading the rest of the code.

Any thoughts? I dug through the manual and nothing jumped out as a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: "javascript",
            matchBrackets: true
        });
        editor.setSize(400, 400);


$('#submit').click(function(){
      //read the next line of code each second
        myVar=setInterval(function(){getCode()},1000);
    });


    function getCode(){
     //only read lines that have code written in them
        var lines = editor.lineCount();

     //get all the code on that specific line
        var code = editor.getRange({'line': i, 'ch': 0}, {'line': i, 'ch': 255});


//highlight
        editor.removeLineClass(i-1, 'background', 'highlight');
        editor.addLineClass(i, 'background', 'highlight');

//evaluate code (this will be replaced with a library eventually for security reasons)
        eval(code);
        i++;

//stop once all lines have been read
        if(i > lines){
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser to get a more abstract view of the code. Since the student might be editing the code, and it might not be syntactically valid, Acorn's error-tolerant parser might be a good fit. See http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/acorn and http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/parse-dammit.html